# How to split strings into substring start with some characters in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring, nsrange

I am stuck in finding the solution of splitting the string into substrings. I need some proper logic in which I need to read string starting with some character and it should contain at least 17 characters.

e.g. "43 01 08 43 13 01 18 **FD 48 6B D1** 43 01 22 02 01 02 02 **F1 48 6B D1** 43 02 03 03 51 03 52 **75 48 6B D1** 43 03 53 11 08 15 52 **9D 48 6B D1** 43 16 14 16 32 00 00"

For Above string , I need to split in into 
"43 01 08 43 13 01 18"
"43 01 22 02 01 02 02"
"43 02 03 03 51 03 52"
"43 03 53 11 08 15 52"
"43 16 14 16 32 00 00"

So On... I mean I need to get the position of "43" ,then from its index i Need to read 20 characters (Including space) and reject the characters until the next "43" appears (BOLD characters as mentioned above). Thanks in advance .. :)

Comment: Show what you have tried??

Comment: I believe NSScanner is the best way to handle these kind of logic.

Comment: I was trying the sample code for http://pastebin.com/cHpGL1Gr but if there is any response which contains the "43" in between the string then it wont work !!

Comment: You said you need to read 20 chars from the '43', but in the example you provide, it seems you read only 10...

Comment: @neutrino blankSpace is also a character !! :)

Comment: @ShrenikShah Ok! I thought each char was written in hex, and so I expected space to be 20. Excuse my silly comment :-)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `rangeOfString:` to locate the next 43, take the 20 characters from there on with `substringWithRange:`, and start over with the remaining substring (`substringFromIndex:`).

```
NSString *str = @"43 01 08 43 13 01 18 FD 48 6B D1 43 01 22 02 01 02 02 F1 48 6B D1 43 02 03 03 51 03 52 75 48 6B D1 43 03 53 11 08 15 52 9D 48 6B D1 43 16 14 16 32 00 00";
NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray array];
NSRange range = { .length = 20 };
while ((range.location = [str rangeOfString:@"43"].location) != NSNotFound
       && str.length >= range.length + range.location) {
    [substrings addObject:[str substringWithRange:range]];
    str = [str substringFromIndex:range.location + range.length];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   NSMutableArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *allString = @"43 01 08 43 13 01 18 FD 48 6B D1 43 01 22 02 01 02 02 F1 48 6B D1 43 02 03 03 51 03 52 75 48 6B D1 43 03 53 11 08 15 52 9D 48 6B D1 43 16 14 16 32 00 00";

    while (allString.length>0) {
        [output addObject:[allString substringToIndex:20]];
        allString = [allString substringFromIndex:20];
        NSArray *arr = [allString componentsSeparatedByString:@"43"];

       if (arr.count>1){
          allString =@"43";
          for (int i=1;i<arr.count;i++){
              allString = [allString stringByAppendingString:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
          }
       }else{
          allString=@"";
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your sequence always starts with "43" and is seven items long.

Split the string and walk down the array creating sub arrays.

```
-(NSArray *)splitString:(NSString *)masterString
{
    NSArray *values = [masterString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSMutableArray *outputarray = [@[] mutableCopy];

    NSUInteger marker = 0;

    NSString *startValue = @"43";

    NSUInteger subarraycount = 7;

    BOOL foundFlag = YES;

    while (foundFlag) {

        NSRange checkRange = NSMakeRange(marker, (values.count - marker));

        NSUInteger next = [values indexOfObject:startValue inRange:checkRange];

        foundFlag = (next != NSNotFound) && ((next + subarraycount) < values.count);

        if (foundFlag) {

            NSRange subrange = NSMakeRange(next, subarraycount);

            NSArray *subarray = [values subarrayWithRange:subrange];

            [outputarray addObject:[subarray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];

            marker = next + subarraycount;
        }

    }

    return [outputarray copy];

}
```